# Is Level One's Trunking feature like LAG/Etherchannel or is it used for VLANs?

Tags: networking, vlan, bonding, trunk, network-teaming

I have a couple of Level One GSW-2476 switches. They allow setting a port's membership in one of eight trunks. Up until now, I thought of trunking as being like LAG groups, i.e. load balancing/aggregation/redundancy. After configuring some ports to be in a trunk and getting all sorts of weird issues when connecting them with multiple patch cables, I researched a bit and learned about Cisco's use of "trunking" meaning allowing multiple VLANs rather than aggregation.
Now I wonder if the issues I've seen are not because of wrong settings but because of me mistaking the feature. The manual isn't very clear on this, either.

What does Level One refer to when they talk about "trunking"?

Answer (score 1):

Trunking means allowing multiple VLANs via one physical or LAG port. I've read documentation and decide that Level One GSW-2476 switch doesn't support LAG. Also it doesn't support STP and loopback detection. May be you had network ring issue. If you want to use LAG between servers, then use it as RoundRobin method via VLAN per port.